# unknown error: cannot determine loading status error using chrome=104.0.5112.81 with Cucumber and Selenium::WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

Does anyone know why this error is occurring during a selenium test?
I'm switching from page during the test. I have also noticed that when a test don't switch page it behaves normally, and the test passed.

```
unknown error: cannot determine loading status
      from unknown error: unexpected command response
        (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
      Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00C96463+2188387]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C2E461+1762401]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B43D78+802168]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B37210+750096]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B3675A+747354]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B35D3F+744767]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B34C28+740392]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B35228+741928]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B3EF2F+782127]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B49FBB+827323]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B4D310+840464]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B354F6+742646]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B49BF3+826355]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B9CF6D+1167213]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B8C5F6+1099254]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B66BE0+945120]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B67AD6+948950]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F371F2+2712546]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F2886D+2652765]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D2002A+520730]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D1EE06+516086]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C3468B+1787531]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C38E88+1805960]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C38F75+1806197]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C41DF1+1842673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76AEFA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CC7A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CC7A6E+238]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
unknown error: cannot determine loading status
      from unknown error: unexpected command response
    (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
      Backtrace:
        .
        .
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CC7A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CC7A6E+238]
```

...implies that there is some mismatch between the *chromedriver* and the *chrome* versions.

---

### Solution

As you are using *`chrome=104.0.5112.81`* ensure that you have download [***`chromedriver=104.0.5112.79`***](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) and using the same.

Comment: worked fine, but why google didn't publish a new version of the driver